# CollapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement CollapsingToolbarLayout with a NestedScrollView and it is displaying the TextView within the NestedScrollView at the bottom and not allowing, scrolling or collapsing the Toolbar. I have gotten this to work with a RecyclerView but not NestedScrollView.  When I remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` the Toolbar collapses but the NestedScrollView is not below the AppBarLayout.  Any solutions or suggestions to fix this?

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="134dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in CoordinatorLayout and the NestedScrollView. Next move the nestedScrollview above the AppBarLayout.

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ Just updated my answer with what you asked. Still same result.

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ If you have a simple working example of this, post it and I will test it out.

Comment: Change `android:layout_height="300dp"` in the AppbarLayout. Ya I had refereed to a project earlier, let.me search that. Meanwhile try this out

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ Tried it out, still no luck.  Any luck on that reference?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ It ended up working.  Thanks.  One thing I noticed, was that if there is not enough views to fill the screeen, it automatically aligns them to the bottom, which could have been causing the issue earlier.

Comment: Ya thats true..I just noticed there is not much to scroll

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ Btw Thanks a lot.  If you post your answer below I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Isn't AppBarLayout supposed to be the first child of CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: It's a known bug, see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175732

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change to some certain height in the AppbarLayout. Example:

```
android:layout_height="300dp".
```

The main problem being, the nested scroll view does not have enough views to cause a scroll. Hence the parallax effect would not work.

[Here is a working example that uses NestedScrollView and CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml#L121)

Comment: I didn't need to set a specific size on my NestedScrollView, just had to set the height to match_parent instead of wrap_content and I was able to collapse the AppBarLayout without any views in the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and wrote kind of quick fix for that. Assuming, that your `LinearLayout` containing "Hello" label is bound to `mContainer` and your `Toolbar` is bound to `mToolbar` you can use this:

```
private void fixNestedScrollViewScrolling() {
    final int bottomMargin = getScreenHeight() - mContainer.getHeight() - mToolbar.getHeight();
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            mContainer.getLayoutParams());
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, bottomMargin);
    mContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}

private int getScreenHeight() {
    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size.y;
}
```

This fix method is called in `onCreate` method of my `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_post);

    fixNestedScrollViewScrolling();

    // some other stuff here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add CoordinatorLayout to make it works:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <!--Your layout here-->

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!--And here-->

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

PS: with android support library change 
`androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout` to `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

and
`androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` to `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`